# Does IIS / ASP.NET make use of TCP keepalive option? (this question is not about the HTTP Keep-Alive)

Tags: asp.net, iis, keep-alive

Does IIS / ASP.NET make use of TCP keepalive option? What are the config parameters that affect it's use?

Please note that this question is not about the HTTP Keep-Alive option.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. You can tell I am new here.

Comment: Your same question here : [How does IIS / ASP.NET handle dead connections? no HTTP Keep-Alive in effect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832072/how-does-iis-asp-net-handle-dead-connections-no-http-keep-alive-in-effect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are making more then 1 request per session, you should be using keep-alives to make sure that the connection stays open - this will improve your web server's performance especially under load.  For SSL, this is even more important since there is much more overhead per connection.

Check http keep alive in this link -

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739467(WS.10).aspx